# C# - Get File Size of Download by intercepting Web Traffic?

Tags: c#, web-services

I would like to detect the file size of a file in bytes before it downloads or perhaps when it initially starts. The tricky part is that I am using a 3rd party SDK to interact with the web services. They offer no method to get the file size. I was wondering if it would be possible to intercept the post response to determine the total file size? Could be a shot in the dark..

```
        public void getExport(string jid, bool compression)
    {
        bool comp = false;
        while (comp == false)
        {
            comp = _eb.IsComplete(jid);
        }

        //capture filesize of download & report back???????????

        byte[] b = this._eb.Retrieve(jid, compression);

        this._eb.Delete(jid);
        this._ws.Destroy();

        this._export = b;

    }
```

In the above script, I have already built an export which is saved as a Job on the server. This process returned the Job ID or jid. The script then initiates the download by passing the jid into the retrieve method. This returns a byte[]. Since they do not offer this functionality, is there something I could wrap all this in so that I can update a progress bar appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HEAD VERB in http to get the metadata of the resource

for example if you want to download the .pdf file at the following location

you use the following command

HEAD "https://www.depts.ttu.edu/upwardbound/books/the-7-habits-ofhighly-effective-people.pdf"

The following information will be returned without downloading the file if you see the content length will give the size of the file to be downloaded.

Accept-Ranges →bytes
**Content-Length →777476**
Content-Type →application/pdf
Date →Mon, 13 Feb 2017 20:32:29 GMT
ETag →"9a3a29bac9ecd11:0"
Last-Modified →Tue, 02 Aug 2016 14:25:32 GMT
Server →Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET

You can use tool like POSTMAN to check this

www.getpostman.com

ALSO Read about HEAD VERB here

www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Ill look into working this in. That is a great read by the way!

Comment: I was going to answer with a very similar answer - it will be in the header.  Otherwise, there's no way to know.

Comment: my issue is how to work the above answer in. The have the sdk handle most everything so Im going to have to get creative with intercepting and injecting the HEAD verb.